# Get value from xml variable sql

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, sqlxml

Hello i am using SQL and have the following value in a variable

```
<needs xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../docs/xsd/rx/i2.0/needs-i2.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Method qid="String" isApplicable="true" location="needs"
        source="needs">
        <Yes>false</Yes>
        <No>true</No>
    </Method>
    <S_Needs qid="String" isApplicable="true" location="needs"
        source="needs">
        <N_Value type="String" id="String" from="String"> NEED THIS VALUE </N_Value>
    </S_Needs>
    <Testing qid="String" isApplicable="true" location="needs"
        source="needs">
        <Yes>false</Yes>
        <No>false</No>
        <Defaults>true</Defaults>
    </Testing>
</needs>
```

The route is needs , S_Needs , N_Value i need N_Value how can i get this value

Answer (score 1):

```
select @XML.value('(/needs/S_Needs/N_Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15962)